# Cas 5.x: How to get access token and refresh token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, cas

I am working on CAS SSO implementation and i am able to authenticate a user and get his attributes.
I am now trying to get access token and refresh token?
According to CAS documentation, we should hit to below URL to get access token:

```
/cas/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK
```

But when i am trying to hit the URL, i am getting below response.

```
<302 Found,{X-Application-Context=[localhost:native:8443], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=96369B02EB5F81B5BEC099D3D7168EE9;path=/cas;Secure;HttpOnly], Location=[localhost:8443/cas/login?service=localhost%3A8443%2Fcas%2Foauth2.0%2FcallbackAuthorize%3Fclient_name%3DCasOAuthClient], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Thu, 18 May 2017 04:10:39 GMT]}>
```

Code i have written to hit the cas URL is below

```
OauthAuthCodeVO abcVO = new OauthAuthCodeVO("token", "clientId", "https://localhost:443/index.html");

  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  HttpEntity<OauthAuthCodeVO> entity = new HttpEntity<>(abcVO, headers);
  ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> resp = restTemplate.exchange("https://localhost:8443/cas/oauth2.0/authorize",  HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
  });
  if (resp != null) {
  System.out.println(resp.getBody());     
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Which Server are you using

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Please read OAuth2 Doco: https://oauth.net/2/

In general, you need three services:

```
/authorize ==> Redirects to login page (if required) and returns auth token
/token ==> Use auth token to get access and refresh token
/refresh ==> use refresh token to get new token (when present one has expired)
```